# Regular expression usage in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like "*First set of digits starts here.and ends with0.762348..another text starts here and :: end up with same kind of digit 0.7234632;third text starts here--that too ends with same kind of digit format0.67343--*"

I am trying to get the numbers starts with "0.", and needs to be split by that number.

**Example output:**

1st Object - First set of digits starts here.and ends with, 0.762348

2nd Object - another text starts here and :: end up with same kind of digit, 0.7234632

3rd Object - third text starts here--that too ends with same kind of digit format, 0.67343

I understand this can be done in regular expression in JavaScript. I tried this:

```
var strr = ""First set of digits starts here.and ends with0.762348..another text starts here and :: end up with same kind of digit 0.7234632;third text starts here--that too ends with same kind of digit format0.67343--""

var regx = strr.replace(\0.[0.9]*symbols\i, \0.[0.9]*&&&&\i);
```

As I am new to regular expressions, I am not clear to execute this scenario. is there any help?

Comment: I suggest some basic research, such as reading [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). That would at least show you that regular expressions are written with slashes (`/`), not backslashes, around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do matching instead of splitting.

```js
var s = "First set of digits starts here.and ends with0.762348..another text starts here and :: end up with same kind of digit 0.7234632;third text starts here--that too ends with same kind of digit format0.67343--";
alert(s.match(/\w.*?0\.\d+/g))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This code alerts with comma in between the sentences, But the next step is need to split upto comma to separate sentences. One more thing, the string may have comma also.

Comment: those are three seperate strings stored in an array. It displays comma only to differentiate the array elements.

Comment: Yes, Issue got fixed. Thanks :)